# Is it possible to have more than one basic variables in the same equation for simplex method?

Tags: linear-programming

I solve this linear programing problem. But I realized there are more than one basic variable (a variable appearing in only one equation) are present in the same equation. Is it possible to happen or I am making some mistake?
There are a lot of variables in the program. 
51 equations and 5052 variables!

Comment: Is "equation" a constraint in the original problem, or in the simplex tableau?

Comment: There is one objective function and 50 inequalities that are changed into equalities. I also have 100 equalities in the original problem that I used to eliminate 100 variables in simplex tableau.

Comment: and do you have more than one basic variable in one row of the simplex tableau?

Comment: YES! I have that problem.

Comment: That cannot happen. As soon as you create the second basic variable, the first one becomes nonbasic.